# Mailchimp Ignoring Media Query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, mailchimp

I have a mailchimp template with a custom code block in the body. This is the preview from Mailchimp:

http://us1.campaign-archive1.com/?u=522bc47724938968956373305&id=52fae71f15&e=

I built this code in jsbin.com and it looks like this:

http://jsbin.com/niquxa/edit?html,css,output

Why is Mailchimp ignoring my media queries for screen size/width to transform the objects properly from 2x2 to 1x4

Also, the the background image does not load in email - only when "view in browser" is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As silly as it sounds, the `!important` addition to certain styles helped solve the problem. Mailchimp still suggests using a custom template instead of overrides.

*NOTE* The "background" image/color isn't supported in Gmail or Outlook very well, depending on the styling being in the body or the head.